# How can I recover the contents of a preserved Chrome Login Data database following a Windows password change?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, encryption, passwords, decryption

So I have a machine here whose owner recently changed their Windows login password - and I learned all at once that the passwords in Chrome's password store are encrypted using the OS login credentials, and that the moment the login credentials change, those encrypted passwords immediately become unreadable. Yay.

Naturally browser sync was unfortunately disabled on the machine in question :')

The one possible (?) mercy is that the new Login Data database was created using a different name, so I was able to grab a copy of the (300KB+) original.

And so I am faced with a seemingly-impossible scenario: **how can I consume a list of *"oh it might have been..."* candidates for the previous Windows password, and use this list to try and decrypt the encrypted passwords?**

Most sources I'm reading suggest Chrome just hands off to Windows' `CryptProtectData` API (which looks like a very scary wall to even consider scaling), although this is completely contradicted by https://github.com/ohyicong/decrypt-chrome-passwords which suggests that I simply need to grab a string out of the `Local State` file (which of course I sadly don't have a copy of D:) and pass that to an AES decryption function.

I'm really interested to find out if there's any foothold here that I might be able to get started with which I'm just not seeing.

Comment: I assume the reason the users password was reset not changed, and I do mean reset, because if it was changed this problem wouldn’t exist is because they forgot the password to the Windows user.

Comment: Noooooo. I've learned this is what actually happened - an admin logged in and reset the user's password from the admin account. So this rotated a bunch of internal crypto keys then? D: is there anything I might be able to fish out of a corner possibly...? :/

Comment: Windows warned whomever reset the user's account this would happen.

Comment: Arggg. So basically, the TL;DR is that all the significant key material backing the passwords in `Login Data` is irrevocably gone... to the extent that, for example, scanning the raw disk image would be of no use?

Comment: You encrypted your passwords and then deleted the key.  However, "I sadly don't have a copy of D:) and pass that to an AES decryption function." I can't tell if you are saying YOU DO have a copy or you don't have a copy.  You use a emoicon for some reason in a serious question.

Comment: Fair question, I was saying "I don't have a copy of the file :(" however I've been going through some old backups and realized I'm incorrect - I have found a few hopeful-looking `Local State` files that are months old (possibly good??) - but NirSoft's ChromePass utility doesn't seem to be doing anything interesting with them, it just thinks for a minute then displays a giant list with the Password column blank :(

Comment: Sounds like the key isn't the same, and thus, cannot be used to decrypt the data.